# How to calculate variance with C++?

Tags: variance

This is what I have so far. I am not able to get the right variance.

```
variance += ((numbers[i] - (double)mean) * (numbers[i] - (double)mean));
variance /= (double)size;
cout << "The variance is: " << variance << endl;
```

Comment: Why is mean an integer?

Comment: total / size will round down

Comment: Why you are not using `numbers[0]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your code, all of which contribute to the variance being wrong.

1. You are calculating the variance in the loop, while updating the mean every iteration (before you have the correct mean). While this will result in the correct mean being stored in the `mean` variable at the end of the loop, the variance will have been computed with an incorrect mean in all but the last iteration.
   You need the mean of *all* the numbers *before* you start subtracting it from the array to compute the variance. The solution would be another loop to calculate the variance after the original loop, at which point you already have the correct mean.
2. Array indices start at 0, but you start at 1, which means the fist number in your array will always be 0, and you are calculating mean and variance of 9 numbers instead of 10, but dividing by 10.
3. Mean is an integer, but is meant to store a floating point (or double precision) number. Additionally, `total / size` will round down since they are both integers, so you should cast one of them to double.

Answer (score 2):

Put

```
    variance += ((numbers[i] - (double)mean) * (numbers[i] - (double)mean));
```

outside the first for loop in another for loop.
And the code will become like this-

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 int arraySize = 10;
 int numbers[10];
 int input, total = 0, size = 0, mean = 0;
 double variance = 0;
 for (int i = 1; i < arraySize; i++) {
    cout << "Enter number " << i << " (-1 to end): ";
    cin >> input;
    if (input == -1) {
        break;
    }
    else {
        numbers[i] = input;
    }
    total += numbers[i];
    size++;
    
    mean = total / size;
    
       
}
for(int i=1; i<=size;i++)
variance += ((numbers[i] - (double)mean) * (numbers[i] - (double)mean));

variance /= (double)size;
cout << "The mean is: " << mean << endl;
cout << "The variance is: " << variance << endl;
}
```

While calculating variance you need the mean of all the numbers in array not the mean after each input.